# Retrieving value from dynamic drop down menu for form input

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a form which has a dynamic drop down menu that retrieves the dealership_id from the dealership table, and once the drop down is selected and the form is submitted it inserts that value into another table on the database. This works ok on my server.

What I am trying to do is retrieve the "users_dealer_name" value in the same row, make it a variable ($dealer_name) and then print that variable in an email message, ie if it retrieves id=3 I want it to print "Mike Chan" but it comes up blank. Where am I going wrong?

dealership database sample

```
dealership_id | users_dealer_name 
1             | John Smith
2             | Jane Smith
3             | Mike Chan
```

Validation code

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['dealership_id'])) {
$dealer_id = (int) $_POST['dealership_id'];

$query2 = 'SELECT users_dealer_name FROM dealership WHERE dealership_id=$dealer_id';
$dealer_name = @mysql_query($query2);

} else {
$dealer_id = 0;
}
if ($dealer_id > 0) {
$query = "SELECT dealership_id
          FROM dealership 
          WHERE dealership_id=$dealer_id";
$result = mysql_query ($query); }
else { echo '<p><font color="red">Please select your Dealership </font></p>'; }
?>
```

Dynamic drop down

```
<?php 
require_once ('database.php');  
echo '<select name="dealership_id"><option value="NULL">Choose a Dealer:</option>'; 
$query = 'SELECT * FROM dealership ORDER BY users_dealer_name ASC';
$result = mysql_query ($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
echo "<option value=\"$row[0]\" ";
if (isset($_POST['dealership_id']) && $_POST['dealership_id'] == $row[0]){
    echo ' selected=\"selected\"';
}
echo ">$row[3]</option>";
}
echo '</select> ';
mysql_close();  
?>
```

Comment: $dealer_name is never used, is there more code?
Also why are you supressing the errors with @mysql_query($query2)? Can you explain which part of the scripts fail?

Comment: Would it help if I posted the whole code? I only want it to print in a message like this, the other fields print ok.

<?php
$adminmessage = 
"The following person is now a new member:
Name: $ufn $usn
Email: $e
Password: $p
Dealer Name: $dealer_name";
mail('email@address.com','Email Title',
$adminmessage, 'From: admin@mysite.com');
?>